# No class error for retrieving a file from FTP with Java

Tags: java

I am trying to make a java program that will get a csv file from FTP and update the database with it . So i started first with retrieving the file but I get the No Class Def Found Error on the FTPClient. Thats my code below .(i have imported the commons-net-3.6.jar and i use jdk-13.0.2 and i use Eclipse if that makes any difference)

```
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;

public class main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String server = "serverip";
    int port = 21;
    String user = "user";
    String pass = "pass";

   FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
    try {

        ftpClient.connect(server, port);
        ftpClient.login(user, pass);
        ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
        ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

        String remoteFile1 = "filename.csv";
        File downloadFile1 = new File("C:/filename.csv");
        OutputStream outputStream1 = new BufferedOutputStream(new 
        FileOutputStream(downloadFile1));
        boolean success = ftpClient.retrieveFile(remoteFile1, outputStream1);
        outputStream1.close();

        if (success) {
            System.out.println("File #1 has been downloaded successfully.");
        }

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (ftpClient.isConnected()) {
                ftpClient.logout();
                ftpClient.disconnect();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
 }
```

**Stacktrace:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient
    at main.main(main.java:18)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: Have you updated the project after importing of the jars?

Comment: @dariosicily What do you mean update ?  I closed and opend the project again and did refresh on Eclipse .

Comment: You should provide a stacktrace too

Comment: @IQbrod Just did .

Comment: Did you re-build the whole project?

Comment: @Melvin I used clean on project menu and there is auto build option on .

Comment: Check your classpath to make sure the commons-net library is correctly added.

Comment: @Roddy of the Frozen Peas You were right , on run configurations , on dependencies tab the commons-net jar wasnt on classpath but on Modulepath . When i changed it , it worked , thank you for the tip